# Do ammo powers from different squad mates stack?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Powers like warp ammo and cryo ammo allow you to affect the entire squad with 50% effectiveness if you take the right upgrade path.

If two squad members use such powers, will the effects stack? Does it make a difference if the powers are different or the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Whichever Ammo power was used most recently will take precedence and erase the previously active one.

If you'd like 2 party members to benefit from squad ammo while a third uses something different, activate the Squad ammo power, then activate the individual ammo power you'd like to use.